# Raspberry Pi Relay BoardをWindows10 IoTで動かしたい

Tags: raspberry-pi, vb.net, windows-10

Raspberry Pi3にRaspberry Pi Relay Board v1.0をつけて
Windows10 IoT core + VB.NET でコントロールしたいと思っています。

Raspberry Pi Relay Board v1.0
http://wiki.seeed.cc/Raspberry_Pi_Relay_Board_v1.0/

Pythonのコードはあるのですが、どうやってVB.NETで書けばよいかわかりません。
I2Cデバイスとの接続はできましたが、どんなバイト値を書き込めば動くのかさっぱりです。
どなたかサポート頂けませんでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

なんとかPythonライブラリをVB.NET化し、動作可能になったので
自己解決ですが、クラス化したものを残しておきます。
バイト値（2進数）をいじるのは難しいですね・・・

```
Imports Windows.Devices.Enumeration
Imports Windows.Devices.I2c

Friend Class RelayDevice

    Private Const DEVICE_NAME As String = "I2C1" 'Raspbery PIではこれがデフォルト
    Private Const DEVICE_MODE As Byte = &H6 '00000110
    Private DEVICE_DATA As Byte = &HFF '11111111

    Private _deviceAddress As Byte

    Private RelayDevice As I2cDevice

    Public Sub New(DEVICE_ADDRESS As Byte)
        '&H20 00100000がデフォルト値
        _deviceAddress = DEVICE_ADDRESS
        InitI2cDevice()
    End Sub

    Private Async Sub InitI2cDevice()
        'デバイスを初期化し、使えるようにする
        Dim deviceName = I2cDevice.GetDeviceSelector(DEVICE_NAME)
        Dim deviceList = Await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(deviceName)
        Dim deviceId = deviceList(0).Id
        Dim connectionSetting = New I2cConnectionSettings(_deviceAddress)
        connectionSetting.BusSpeed = I2cBusSpeed.FastMode
        connectionSetting.SharingMode = I2cSharingMode.Exclusive

        RelayDevice = Await I2cDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceId, connectionSetting)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Dispose()
        RelayDevice.Dispose()
    End Sub

    Public Sub RelayOn(RelayNum As Integer)
        '11111110 でリレー１だけ点灯
        '11111101 でリレー２だけ点灯
        '11111011 でリレー３だけ点灯
        '11110111 でリレー４だけ点灯
        'DEVICE_REG_DATA &= ~(0x1 << (relay_num - 1))
        DEVICE_DATA = CByte(DEVICE_DATA And (Not (&H1 << (RelayNum - 1))))
        RelayDevice.Write(New Byte() {DEVICE_MODE, DEVICE_DATA})
    End Sub

    Public Sub RelayOff(RelayNum As Integer)
        '11110001 でリレー１だけ消灯
        '11110010 でリレー２だけ消灯
        '11110100 でリレー３だけ消灯
        '11111000 でリレー４だけ消灯
        'DEVICE_REG_DATA |= (0x1 << (relay_num - 1))
        DEVICE_DATA = CByte(DEVICE_DATA Or (&H1 << (RelayNum - 1)))
        RelayDevice.Write(New Byte() {DEVICE_MODE, DEVICE_DATA})
    End Sub

    Public Sub RelayOnAll()
        DEVICE_DATA = &HF0 '11110000 ですべて点灯
        RelayDevice.Write(New Byte() {DEVICE_MODE, DEVICE_DATA})
    End Sub

    Public Sub RelayOffAll()
        DEVICE_DATA = &HFF '11111111 ですべて消灯
        RelayDevice.Write(New Byte() {DEVICE_MODE, DEVICE_DATA})
    End Sub

End Class
```